# How implement fingerprint scanner in WebApp?

Tags: fingerprint, progressive-web-apps

I want use sensor of android to get fingerprint. I have a **WebApp** and want to get callback of fingerprint. Is possible implement fingerprint scanner in **WebApp**? Using Javascript or something like that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is now possible to [use the Web Authentication API in all major browsers, including iOS.](https://caniuse.com/#search=webauthn)

This is a very important development for PWAs.

Answer (score 14):

It is now possible to use fingerprint authentication but also other strong authentication methods on Chrome.

The Web Authentication API is introduced and explained in the article below which also contains a video from the Google I/O'18 session that presents and demos its features.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/webauthn

Try the API yourself at https://webauthndemo.appspot.com/

Answer (score 9):

If you want the access to the fingerprint itself, then no, you can't.

If you just want to delegate authentication to the underlying device without caring much how it actually happens, there is a standard for this: [Web Authentication API](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/). The problem with this API (like with other young APIs) is that it is not yet well supported. [In Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5669923372138496) the status is "in development". [Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webauthenticationapi/?q=authen) seems to support it with Microsoft Passport.

But generally, if you're looking for a decent, mature solution, you're out of luck.

Comment: I found solutions using webcam/camera to get fingerprint but I think isn't a good solution..

Comment: Update: feature status is now 'Shipped' in both Chrome and Firefox. (from the linked Chrome development site)

Comment: @FKasa So Now I can add fingerprint security to my webApplication? If so can you please provide me the right direction?

Comment: @pardeep-jain I created a new answer below with updates on the issu as it seemed more appropriate

Comment: **Update in 09 Mar 2019**: W3C Approved in 04 Mar 2019. More details: https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/